# Why the output the program is something different?

Tags: c, file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;
    char buffer[80] ;
    fp = fopen("c:\\Rasmi Personal\\hello.txt", "w");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        while(1)
        {
            gets(buffer);
            fwrite(buffer, strlen(buffer), 2, fp); /* I made, size_t nitems = 2 (third element/argument)*/
            fwrite("\n", 1, 1, fp);
        }

    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
Rasmi Ranjan Nayak
```

Output:

```
Rasmi Ranjan Nayak      0@ ÿ" 8ÿ"
```

Why this garbage is coming.

According to fwrite() function. if the `size_t nitems is more than 1` then the entered text will be written `more than once`.
But here why I am getting garbage?

Comment: Lack of terminating NULL in `buffer`?

Comment: From http://linux.die.net/man/3/gets: Never use gets(). Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use. It has been used to break computer security. Use fgets() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of fwrite function is

```
size_t fwrite ( const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );

ptr
  Pointer to the array of elements to be written.
size
  Size in bytes of each element to be written.
count
  Number of elements, each one with a size of size bytes.
stream
  Pointer to a FILE object that specifies an output stream.
```

In this case, if you try to write count * size who is bigger (in bytes) than the original string you have this garbage. If you clean the buffer

```
memset(buffer,0,80*sizeof(char));
gets(buffer);
```

probably will see a different result

```
$ ./a.out
asdadsadasdsad

$ cat -v hello.txt 
asdadsadasdsad^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

but the text is always writen once. the difference is how many bytes will be writen

Answer (score 4):

You're telling `fwrite()` to write two times `strlen(buffer)` bytes from the buffer (by setting `nmemb = 2` you're making it write two "objects", each of which is `strlen(buffer)` bytes long), so it reads twice the number of bytes that are actually present.

The "garbage" is simply whatever happens to appear in memory after the string ends in `buffer`.

This is broken code, `nmemb` should be `1`.